# Third order Cauchy-Euler differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this:
$$x^3y''' - x^2y'' + 2xy' - 2y = x^3$$

I know that first I have to solve:
$$E = x^3y''' - x^2y'' + 2xy' - 2y = 0$$

I choose $y = x^r$. By feeding that to $E$ it will lead me to the following characteristic equation:
$$(r-2)(r-1)^2=0$$

Now if all roots would be distinct the solution would be simple, but with repeating roots how do I approach this equation?

I know that the correct answer must be:
$$y(x) = c_3 x^2+c_1 x+c_2 x ln(x)+x^3/4$$

I don't know how to get to the $c_2xln(x)$ part. I know that I have to use Wronskian matrix to get the $x^3/4$ part.

Comment: Go to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x^3*y%27%27%27-x^2*y%27%27%2B2*x*y%27-2*y%3Dx^3   you can find the solution and all the steps.

Comment: I did that and WA says this: 'Because of repeated root r = 1 we have the solutions y1 = c1x and y2 = c2xln(x)'. Now my question is Why?. :-s

Comment: @Dr.Optix Read my answer, you'll see why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x^3 y^{′′′}−x^2 y^{′′}+2xy^′−2y=x^3$

Consider the substitution due to Euler:

$e^z = x$

You'll get

$y'=\dfrac{dy}{dx} =\dfrac{dy}{dz}\dfrac{dz}{dx}=e^{-z}\dfrac{dy}{dz}$

So $xy' = \dfrac{dy}{dz} $

Similarily you'll get

$x^2 y'' = \dfrac{d^2y}{dz^2}-\dfrac{dy}{dz}$ or $\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{D}-1)y$

And finally (as you might have guessed by now)

$x^3y''' =\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{D}-1)(\mathcal{D}-2)y$

Note that $\mathcal{D} = \dfrac{d}{dz}$ is our new operator.

Plugging this in gives

$\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{D}-1)(\mathcal{D}-2)y−\mathcal{D}(\mathcal{D}-1)y+2\mathcal{D}y−2y=e^{3z}$

Now factor $y$ and expand, then factor to get

$$\eqalign{
  & \left( {{\mathcal{D}^3} - 4{\mathcal{D}^2} + 5\mathcal{D} - 2} \right)y = {e^{3z}}  \cr 
  & {\left( {\mathcal{D} - 1} \right)^2}\left( {\mathcal{D} - 2} \right)y = {e^{3z}} \cr} $$

So now solve the homogeneous equation:

$${\left( {\mathcal{D} - 1} \right)^2}\left( {\mathcal{D} - 2} \right)y = 0$$

This gives the complementary solution in terms of $z$ or $\log x$

$${y_c} = {c_1}z{e^z} + {c_2}{e^z} + {c_3}{e^{2z}}$$

$${y_c} = {c_1}x\log x + {c_2}x + {c_3}{x^2}$$

You can easily get the particular with the original equation by assuming a solution $y=Ax^3$ and finding $A$.

ADD: In general, the substitution $x = e^z$ will transform

$$\sum\limits_{k = 0}^n {{a_k}{x^k}{D^k}} y = F$$

into a linear equation of constant coefficients.

Comment: Sorry to bump this up but why did you assume $y=Ax^3$ instead of $y=Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D$? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to try using [Laplace](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106675/laplace-of-x2-fracd2ydx2) :
$$x^3y''' - x^2y'' + 2xy' - 2y = x^3$$
$$\implies y''' - y'' + 2y' - 2y = e^{-3t}$$
See above link for substitution details :: $ x = e^{t}$
Henceforth, y prime denotes differentiation wrt t
$$\implies L(y''') - L(y'') + 2L(y') - 2L(y) = L(e^{-3t})$$
Let $L(y) = \phi(s)$

$$\implies (s^3\phi(s)-s^2f(0) -sf'(0) - f''(0)) - (s^2\phi(s)-sf(0) - f'(0)) + 2(s.\phi(s) - f(0)) - 2\phi(s) = \frac{1}{s+3}$$

$$ \phi(s)(s^3 - s^2 + 2s - 2) - f(0)(s^2 -s+2) -f'(0)(s-1) - f''(0) = \frac{1}{s+3}$$
$$ \phi(s)(s^3 - s^2 + 2s - 2) = f(0)(s^2 -s+2) +f'(0)(s-1) + f''(0) + \frac{1}{s+3}$$
$$ \phi(s)= \frac{f(0)(s^2 -s+2) +f'(0)(s-1) + f''(0) + \frac{1}{s+3}}{(s^3 - s^2 + 2s - 2) }$$

$$ \phi(s)= \frac{f(0)(s^2 -s+2)}{(s^3 - s^2 + 2s - 2)} +\frac{f'(0)(s-1)}{(s^3 - s^2 + 2s - 2)} + \frac{f''(0)}{(s^3 - s^2 + 2s - 2) } +\frac{1}{(s+3)(s^3 - s^2 + 2s - 2) }$$
I hope I haven't made any errors. This should give you an answer. I was going to throw it away but posted it hoping someone might find it useful (or would they?)

Comment: If you could factor out the denominators I guess I'd work, but still, the LT of $x \log x$ involves $\gamma$ so it's kind of a problem and long work.

Comment: @Peter, I factored it in MATLAB and Yes, It is a major pain. As I said, it was an attempt to do it using Laplace.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but feel like the answers given in this thread are way too complicated and although they work, the easier solution is just to look at the repeated root and realize that two of the linearly independent solutions are y1 = c1x and y2 = c2xln(x).

Why? It's easy to prove with reduction of order for a 2nd order linear homogeneous cauchy euler equation. I know your question is 4 years old, so I won't bother typing up a proof for nothing, but if anyone else stumbles upon this thread, you can message me and I'll explain in more detail.